# If you're flying, does dismounting still take a move action?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, mount, flight

If you are mounted and are flying, such as under the affects of a [fly spell](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/fly.htm), does dismounting take a move action still?

The [ride skill](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/ride.htm) seems silent on this, specifically on what actually makes this be a move action (whether it's an increment of time vs avoiding falling off).

The only hint to me is potentially the following quote which states that bareback riding is a ride penalty which could potentially speak to the fact that bareback (fast) dismounting and saddled (fast) dismounting take the same amount of time and the former is just harder to do.

> If you are riding bareback, you take a -5 penalty on Ride checks.

I had originally assumed that there may be additional effort to 'disentangle' yourself from a saddled mount but there's no ruling to this I see nor do I have any real life knowledge of riding, so that quote might be a red herring anyway.

Anyone know of additional rules clarifies or examples that might answer this Q?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There does not appear to be a way in the RAW to fly off of your mount. Getting off of a mount requires a dismount (which you can take as a free action if you beat a DC 20 ride check) and nothing in the fly spell gets rid of this.

Answer (score 4):

[Ride](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/skills/ride.htm) includes:

> Fast Mount or Dismount
>
> You can attempt to mount or dismount from a mount of up to one size category larger than yourself as a free action, provided that you still have a move action available that round. If you fail the Ride check [DC20], mounting or dismounting is a move action. You can’t use fast mount or dismount on a mount more than one size category larger than yourself.

To dismount you must have your move action available, if you succeed on a ride check it is still available after dismounting and can be used, if you fail it is used up in the process of dismounting. It is irrelevant if you have only a normal speed or a fly speed (or for that matter a swim or burrow speed); dismounting is dismounting.

Answer (score 0):

Your DM might allow you to "drop to the floor". That is a free action and RAW does not prohibit it to mounted characters. (Though RAI is probably that you drop with your own feet on the ground, that is why I'd say you need to ask.)

You could then use your move action to stabilize during your fall and the standard action to fireball.

For a non-flying character this would mean he falls prone - quite a price for a "fast dismount". But for mounted characters in water or airborne this might be an option. Personally I would disallow this for mounted characters with stirrups.